# Schedule library starts 20-46 Seconds after the time I set, Not sure why

Tags: python, scheduled-tasks, dayofweek

Trying to run a program every day at exactly 11:59:40 AM when I use the schedule library it will start 20+ Seconds after the time I set, Not sure why. Is there another library I can use? Also tried using Task Scheduler and it says it's running but doesn't perform the actions like it does when running it in Pycharm.

```
import schedule
import time
import webbrowser
from pynput.keyboard import Key, Controller as KeyboardController
from pynput.mouse import Button, Controller as MouseController

url = "https://walmart.com"

def open_site():
    webbrowser.open(url, new=1)
    time.sleep(5)
    keyboard = KeyboardController()
    mouse = MouseController()

    #### Logs in to Site ###
    mouse.position = (800, 530)
    keyboard.press(Key.ctrl_r)
    keyboard.release(Key.ctrl_r)
    mouse.press(Button.left)
    mouse.release(Button.left)
    time.sleep(2)
    keyboard.press(Key.down)
    keyboard.release(Key.down)
    time.sleep(1)
    keyboard.press(Key.enter)
    keyboard.release(Key.enter)
    time.sleep(1)
    keyboard.press(Key.enter)
    keyboard.release(Key.enter)

schedule.every().day.at("11:59:40").do(open_site)

while True:
    schedule.run_pending()
    time.sleep(60)  # wait one minute
```

Answer (score 0):

I didn't realize that the script was starting at the bottom and then going to the top of def open_site. I placed:

print("**Program Started on** " + strftime("%a, " + "at " + "%d %b %Y %H:%M:%S +0000", gmtime()))
Above webbroswer.open(url, new=1)

and then:

print("**Program Ended on** " + strftime("%a, " + "at " + "%d %b %Y %H:%M:%S +1000", gmtime()))

below the last keyboard.release(Key.enter)
then I moved the:
time.sleep(60)
below that. When that first print statement was **Program Ended on** I found the problem. Basically, I used **from time import gmtime, strftime** to see when the script was starting and ending. **I love the EUREKA!!!! moments I get with learning this language.** Here is the updated code.

```
import schedule
import time
import webbrowser
from pynput.keyboard import Key, Controller as KeyboardController
from pynput.mouse import Button, Controller as MouseController
from time import gmtime, strftime

url = "https://walmart.com"

def open_site():
    webbrowser.open(url, new=1)
    time.sleep(5)
    keyboard = KeyboardController()
    mouse = MouseController()

    #### Logs in to Site ###
    mouse.position = (800, 530)
    keyboard.press(Key.ctrl_r)
    keyboard.release(Key.ctrl_r)
    mouse.press(Button.left)
    mouse.release(Button.left)
    time.sleep(2)
    keyboard.press(Key.down)
    keyboard.release(Key.down)
    time.sleep(1)
    keyboard.press(Key.enter)
    keyboard.release(Key.enter)
    time.sleep(1)
    keyboard.press(Key.enter)
    keyboard.release(Key.enter)
    time.sleep(60)
    return

schedule.every().day.at("23:36:00").do(open_site)

while True:
    schedule.run_pending()
    time.sleep(.01)
```